# How to deal with large formatted documents quickly in Ubuntu?

Tags: libreoffice, text-processing

I have a .docx file that have a size of 200MB.

To open or save such huge files, MS Office on Windows 10 only need several seconds, but Libre Office on Ubuntu 22.04 take dozens of seconds.

(FYI: iWork on M1 iPad also take that long time, even MS Office on M1 iPad take much longer time than on Windows 10)

Is there a tool or methodology on Ubuntu that can deal with large formatted documents quickly?

.docx is not required, any format is fine and I can convert the .docx to the required format of the tool.

Basic text formmating, insertion of pictures and subscript/superscript are required.

Open source solution is required, or why not just use Windows?

Comment: Try converting your .docx to a LibreOffice .odt and then see if LibreOffice can open it faster. The use of .docx suggests that you might be unfamiliar with the serious drawbacks of that particular file format. It is recommended for use only with Word. Use with other applications is not recommended.

Comment: Could go with [FreeOffice](https://www.freeoffice.com/en/) too; I find that LibreOffice is a bit heavier on the features than required for basic editing, opening an example 32Mb document takes a full second less (3.5 vs 4.5) in FreeOffice vs LibreOffice. Of course totally depends on your hardware though.